# PageView : How to change scrolling speed and smoothness

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to change the speed of scrolling and make it smooth on this PageView item :

```
PageView.builder(
                // store this controller in a State to save the carousel scroll position
                controller: controller,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
                  return _buildCarouselItem(context, carouselIndex, itemIndex);
                },
                physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: Itmes.length,
                onPageChanged: (int) {
                  OnNext(int);
                },
              )
```

It's not that different but, I must say that I can do the speed change when dynamically switching between pages but as a default option.

**EXPLANATION :** When using a page view, you can scroll the pages, which each scroll an animation is working. that animation take a lof of time and  is much more smoother than I want it to be. My question is Can I speed up that animation and make it a bit sharper ?

Comment: can you clarify your question a little bit more ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim please check my edit

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to change the PageView animation. Did you find anything?

Comment: @offex no not really I just disabled the default scrolling animation and did everything on my own with gesture detectors and all. That also turned out to be very hard so I just left the originals.

Comment: @offex have you checked PageController's `animateToPage` ? You can choose a curve for the transition along with duration -- it might help with what you need to do.

Comment: @J.Saw Isn't that only used for programmatic scrolling? I am wanting to change how long it takes the scrolling snapping animation to end after a user initiates scroll on a PageView and stops scrolling in between pages. I am wanting to shorten that snapping duration because it prevents the user from initiating a drag in the opposite axis until it is completely finished.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @intraector You can it with custom physics. you can start by extending the physics you are already using and edit from there.

Comment: I've tried all the options, there's no way to change the speed no matter how you change the physics. If someone has the sacred knowledge how to achieve it I would've appreciate that.

Comment: @intraector in a custom physics  you need to override this function `createBallisticSimulation`, it will return a `ScrollSpringSimulation`  that takes velocity as fourth argument. there you can set any number you want. 
i did a custom physics for a stageScroll listview here : https://github.com/moda20/flutter-tunein/blob/master/lib/components/stageScrollingPhysics.dart

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime thanks for reponse. That `velocity` only changes the behavior only on two ends of the list, but changes nothing while scrolling in the middle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter PageView how to make faster animations on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325496/flutter-pageview-how-to-make-faster-animations-on-swipe)

Comment: @JMooreLabs yeah that is the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter how to make PageView scroll faster? The animation seems to be slow and the inner ListView cant response my vertical gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320972/in-flutter-how-to-make-pageview-scroll-faster-the-animation-seems-to-be-slow-an)

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you, although this was for ListView. You can change the velocity this way...

```dart
class PageScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  @override
  ScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    return PageScrollPhysics();
  }

  @override
  Simulation createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    return CustomSimulation(
      initPosition: position.pixels,
      velocity: velocity,
    );
  }
}

class CustomSimulation extends Simulation {
  final double initPosition;
  final double velocity;

  CustomSimulation({this.initPosition, this.velocity});

  @override
  double x(double time) {
    var max =
        math.max(math.min(initPosition, 0.0), initPosition + velocity * time);
    return max;
  }

  @override
  double dx(double time) {
    // print(velocity.toString());
    return velocity;
  }

  @override
  bool isDone(double time) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything for PageView. Maybe this code works for ListView only.