# In Flutter how to make PageView scroll faster? The animation seems to be slow and the inner ListView cant response my vertical gesture

Tags: android, flutter

you can see the details in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFyA-X30ozo&feature=youtu.be)

I don't know how to work out this problem.Compared with Android Native ViewPager,the animation of the PageView in Flutter seems to be slower and users only to wait this slow animation to completely stop , they can drag the internal ListView.I feel that the user experience is worse than native android ViewPager.Hoping a perfect solution.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/reactive_page_view/reactive_page_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Page(),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

PageView view;

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: PageView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ItemPage();
          }),
    );
  }
}

class ItemPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('这是第$index', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: ok，I ve done that

Comment: Did you already test your code in release mode? Some of the animations will only be fluent in release mode, because your app will then be much more optimized.

Comment: I have tested that ,just the same like debug mode,I just want to drag vertically faster,instead of waiting the animation to stop.This animation is slower compared with native app which make me uncomfortable

Comment: I have this problem also, the user can't start a vertical drag on a page in my PageView until the horizontal animation is completely finished, which takes a long time to finish. I want a way to make the animation end quicker.

Comment: @offex did you find any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter PageView how to make faster animations on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325496/flutter-pageview-how-to-make-faster-animations-on-swipe)

Comment: Where is the video!!!???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325496/flutter-pageview-how-to-make-faster-animations-on-swipe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can control the general physics of the scroll animation.

```
PageView(
  physics: CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(),
```

**Control the scroll behavior:**

```
class CustomPageViewScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  CustomPageViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor)!);
  }

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
        mass: 50,
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 0.8,
      );
}
```

You should also be able to calculate the duration with mass, stiffness, damping, but I believe having those options is even better suited for your problem. [Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55103#issuecomment-747059541)

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own instance of PageController and use its methods nextPage() and previousPage(). They have "duration" argument that controls how fast the page view scrolls.

```
final PageController controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.9,
  );

  void nextPage() async {
    await controller.nextPage(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  void prevPage() async {
    await controller.previousPage(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }
```

Then apply this controller to your Page View:

```
return PageView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller,
      ...
    );
```

The full code of main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyPageViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPageViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPageViewExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final PageController controller = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.9,
  );

  void nextPage() async {
    await controller.nextPage(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  void prevPage() async {
    await controller.previousPage(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[100],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top, bottom: 20.0),
            child: _buildCarousel(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarousel(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
        return _buildItem(context, itemIndex);
      },
      itemCount: 5,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, top: 10.0, right: 4.0, bottom: 10.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
            nextPage();
          }
          if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
            prevPage();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Item ' + (itemIndex + 1).toString(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great example! Do you think that the native approach cannot be made more responsive? It seems that in the native approach the page needs to be dragged more than 0.5 of the viewport to continue....

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped page view with NotificationListener and disabled pageSnapping. When NotificationListener is called i look for most visble element and scrolls to it

```dart
 return NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        _scrollToCurrentPage(pageController);
        return true;
      },
      child: PageView.builder(
        //page reload is pretty quick, we don't need to keep it in memory
        controller: pageController,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ViewItem(pages[index]),
        itemCount: pages.length,
        pageSnapping: false,
      ),
    );
  }

void _scrollToCurrentPage(PageController pageController) {
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      pageController.page?.round().let((it) => pageController.animateToPage(
            it,
            duration: RConsts.snapPageAnimationDuration,
            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          ));
    });
  }
```

After that, I can scroll pages as fast as list view. I assume you can do it with horizontal list view as well.