# Flutter : How to make PageView scroll speed end fast

Tags: flutter, dart, pageviews

### How to make the scroll animation end faster ?

When scrolling using the PageView widget, i need to wait until PageView scroll animation finish only can start scrolling the ListView that contain inside the new page. How to achieve this situation ?

Comment: check `ScrollPhysics` / `PageScrollPhysics`

Comment: @pskink can you provide an example and explanation ?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: same here, page view is not customable

Comment: This is actually a duplicate question. The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761014/11003497)