# Flutter How do I change the scroll speed in ListView on the mouse wheel?

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop

I'm a beginner. I'm writing an application on Flutter under Windows. The problem is that the text in the ListView scrolls too slowly by the mouse clip. I tried to override ScrollPhysics, but it didn't work. Please give a working way to change the scrolling speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter how to make PageView scroll faster? The animation seems to be slow and the inner ListView cant response my vertical gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320972/in-flutter-how-to-make-pageview-scroll-faster-the-animation-seems-to-be-slow-an)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   class ScrollViewTest extends StatelessWidget{
    
    static const _extraScrollSpeed = 80; // your "extra" scroll speed
    final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  // Constructor
   
    ScrollViewTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key)
    {
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
        ScrollDirection scrollDirection = _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection;
      if (scrollDirection != ScrollDirection.idle)
      {
        double scrollEnd = _scrollController.offset + (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse
                       ? _extraScrollSpeed
                       : -_extraScrollSpeed);
        scrollEnd = min(
                 _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                 max(_scrollController.position.minScrollExtent, scrollEnd));
        _scrollController.jumpTo(scrollEnd);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
    
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Container(...),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

For people finding this post:
Based on the accepted answer above, this custom class that can be *thrown in* and used throughout an application.

**Customized AdjustableScrollController**

```dart
// scrollcontroller.dart

import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AdjustableScrollController extends ScrollController {
  AdjustableScrollController([int extraScrollSpeed = 40]) {
    super.addListener(() {
      ScrollDirection scrollDirection = super.position.userScrollDirection;
      if (scrollDirection != ScrollDirection.idle) {
        double scrollEnd = super.offset +
            (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse
                ? extraScrollSpeed
                : -extraScrollSpeed);
        scrollEnd = min(super.position.maxScrollExtent,
            max(super.position.minScrollExtent, scrollEnd));
        jumpTo(scrollEnd);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```dart
// your_file.dart

ListView(
  controller: AdjustableScrollController() // default is 40
```

or

```dart
// your_file.dart

ListView(
  controller: AdjustableScrollController(80)  // scroll even faster
```

Comment: by use this code, when I use app in touch screen laptop, scrolling by lag!!!