# Slow down scrolling speed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll

I have a problem with slowing down speed in SingleChildScrollView or ListView. So how can I slow down the scrolling speed?

Comment: Hey Zeff Please see this might help you.. Thanks.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356757/flutter-how-do-i-change-the-scroll-speed-in-listview-on-the-mouse-wheel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter how to make PageView scroll faster? The animation seems to be slow and the inner ListView cant response my vertical gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320972/in-flutter-how-to-make-pageview-scroll-faster-the-animation-seems-to-be-slow-an)