# How to slow/fast flutter scroll speed (can be singlechildscrollview, listview or something)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scroll

I have hard time achieving premium app scroll affect/speed like spotify, smooth scrolling with slow speed. But flutter, default speed is too fast which doesn't looks like same as Spotify.

Already tried with changing physics b/w clamping and bouncy they doesn't affect the speed.

If anyone know, please do write back (as soon as possible)
Thanks from Gautam Singh

Comment: Have you looked into something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356757/flutter-how-do-i-change-the-scroll-speed-in-listview-on-the-mouse-wheel