# Flutter PageView how to make faster animations on swipe

Tags: flutter

I have a simple PageView:

```
PageView(
  controller: _pageController,
  physics: PlatformScrollPhysics.getPlatformScrollPhysics(),
  children: [
    Text("I am Text1"),
    Text("I am Text"),
  ],
  onPageChanged: (index) {
    print("page changed $index");
  },
);
```

What I would like to do is I want to make the page changing animation after a swipe is done by user faster. This happens when a user does a swipe and lifts off the finger, PageView snaps to the next page. This snapping currently takes around so much time, provides bad UX. However, there is no option to set the snapping animation speed and duration.

I have tried to add a listener:

```
_pageController.addListener(() {
      _pageController.position // this variable holds lots of information but yet I couldnt find what i looked for
      print("LISTENERRR ${_pageController.position}");
    });
```

Sadly, I couldnt find anything that can help me. I tried to overtake the swipe and make a custom swipe by calling

```
  _pageController.animateToPage(0, .. PARAMS);
```

for this to work, I need to detect when a page is about to change, so that I can overwrrite the animation with `animateToPage` method. Can I detect when a page is about to change in PageView? I am not interested in `onPageChanged` callback as it is late to overwrite the animation.

Comment: @pskink i did and it worked (what I did was I added `velocity *= 2;`to PageScrollPhysics source code), but I still have a problem, the curve this animation does is something like ease out expo, it moves so fast at the beginning but slows does near the end. I want to change this to ease in, If i may ask can you help me?

Comment: ok forget about passing increased `velocity` - instead you should return your custom [spring](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/spring.html) - something like: `@override
  SpringDescription get spring => _yourDefaultSpring;`

Comment: @pskink looking at spring with modes: `A ratio of 1.0 creates a critically damped spring, > 1.0 creates an overdamped spring and < 1.0 an underdamped one.` i looked at the graphs and I see that the ease out expo effect I was talking about probably comes due to the nature of the spring. I don think I can achieve a ease in alike phycis with spring, wouldnt it make sense to write a simulation class instead?

Comment: sure, if you know what you do :-) but before you do that play a bit with less `mass`

Comment: @pskink making mass 0.1 made it perfect, you are like a magician everything you tell is 100% accurate, im very impressed, let me thank you for the help :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Flutter how to make PageView scroll faster? The animation seems to be slow and the inner ListView cant response my vertical gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320972/in-flutter-how-to-make-pageview-scroll-faster-the-animation-seems-to-be-slow-an)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[cs guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9570941/cs-guy)'s answer is right on track. Also credit to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink).The PageView widget's transition speed isn't based on an animation curve even though the programmatic approach is.

**PageView actually uses a Spring Simulation to handle the page transitions when used with swiping**, so the "physics" property has to be overridden to change the "animation speed".

Here is a simple way to increase the "animation speed" by using custom Scroll Physics class.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';

class CustomPageViewScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics parent})
      : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  CustomPageViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    return CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
        mass: 80,
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 1,
      );
}
```

It can be used in the PageView constructor like this:

```
PageView(... physics: const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(),)
```

And feel free to adjust any of the spring parameters!

Comment: Very well made! Clean, maintainable code. Accepted as answer!

Comment: Blimey! This works like a charm! Great work

Comment: how to map this with animation duration if I want change manually same

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class CustomPageViewScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
 const CustomPageViewScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent})
  : super(parent: parent);

 @override
 CustomPageViewScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
   return CustomPageViewScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
 }
 @override
 SpringDescription get spring => const SpringDescription(
  mass: 100,
  stiffness: 100,
  damping: 1,
 );
}
```